# elastic search multi query with alpakka-elasticsearch client

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, alpakka

I am new to scala, using alpakka-elasticsearch client to perform query with elastic search.

Single search query is working fine with below two ways which internally calls to _search url of elastic search:

```
val writeCustomIndex = ElasticsearchSource
 .typed[Book](
  indexName = "source",
  typeName = "_doc",
  query = """{"match_all": {}}"""
 )
```

OR

```
val readWithSearchParameters = ElasticsearchSource
.typed[TestDoc](
  indexName,
  Some(typeName),
  searchParams = Map(
  "query" -> """ {"match_all": {}} """,
  "_source" -> """ ["id", "a", "c"] """
  )
```

What I am looking for is to perform below multi query(_msearch) with this client.

```
url - http://localhost:9200/index1/_msearch?
request :
[
 {"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 1},
 {"index" : "index2"},
 {"query" : {"match_all" : {}}, "from" : 0, "size" : 2}
]
```

elastic client source : https://doc.akka.io/docs/alpakka/current/elasticsearch.html

Comment: I think you should merge separate sources (one for each search request) by something like https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/merge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried with one approach as per suggestion, where I have merged two sources.

Hope, this may help someone!

```
 var elasticRecord: Future[Seq[ElasticRecord]] = ElasticsearchSource
  .typed[ElasticRecord](
  indexName1,
  Some(typeName1),
  query1,
  settings = ElasticsearchSourceSettings()).map { message =>
  message.source
}.merge(ElasticsearchSource
  .typed[ElasticRecord](
  indexName2,
  Some(typeName2),
  query1,
  settings = ElasticsearchSourceSettings()).map { message =>
  message.source
}).runWith(Sink.seq)
```